# To-Do Cross Off List & Closures

Tags: javascript, list, closures, scopes

I know I can simply invoke function crossOff inside function addList. However, I want to know where my logic has gone off, and how to think correctly...so when I am storing addList function to the variable crossOff2 and then calling crossOff2, I thought that the crossOff function will be invoked since it is stored in crossOff2. So why doesn't crossOff function seem to be working?
My other question is if replaced `button2.addEventListener('click', addList)` to `button2.addEventListener('click', crossOff2)` why doesn't it work as well since crossOff2 is invoking addList?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
   <h1 id="title">Welcome to the DOM</h1>
    <p>Don't feel <span class="blue">blue</span>, here's what to do.</p>
    <button id="generate-greeting">Hello</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label for="new-todo">Add a new item to the list:</label>
    <input id="new-todo" type="text">
    <button id="generate-todo">Add to the List!</button>
    <h1>List of things to do</h1>
    <ul class="todos">
    </ul>
<script>
function addList(){
  const containerList = document.querySelector(".todos")
  const list = document.createElement("li")
  const getInput = document.querySelector("#new-todo")
  list.innerText = getInput.value
  containerList.appendChild(list)
  getInput.value = ''
  function crossOff(){
    list.addEventListener('click', function styling(e){
    e.target.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  })
  }
  return crossOff
}
let crossOff2 = addList()
crossOff2()

const button2 = document.getElementById("generate-todo")
button2.addEventListener('click', addList)

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*crossOff2 is invoking addList?*" - no, it's not.

Comment: "*I am storing addList function to the variable crossOff2*" - no, you're storing the result of the `addList()` call in that variable. (The result is a function, yes, a closure even, that you can invoke later, but `addList` already has been called when you use `crossOff2`).

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, so I understand the first part that crossOff2 is only storing the result of addList(). So how do I get the function crossOff to work if it's now saved in crossOff2? I tried just doing crossOff2() but nothing happens - the list isn't crossed off.

Comment: Your `function crossOff(){…}` doesn't cross off the list item, it only installs the event listener that will do so.

Comment: But if that's the case, how come I can simply invoke function crossOff instead of returning and the list is called. Wouldn't it not cross the list off if you said function crossOff only serves to add an event listener?

Comment: My goal is to combine what I learned about closures and eventListeners together. So how can I do this for this code?

Comment: You can make `function styling` a closure by referring to `list` instead of `e.target`. As you said you already know, there's not much to be gained here by not just installing the event listener directly inside `addList`.

Comment: So, I am still missing something...so if I just change it to the following:
`function crossOff(){
    list.addEventListener('click', function styling(e){
    list.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  })`

Comment: And then drop the `crossOff` function completely and just run the `list.addEventListener()`  directly from within `addList` (like you suggested in the first sentence of the question).

Comment: @Bergi However is there anyway to do a closure to apply the cross off part ? (I know it's more complicated, but I want to make sure I know how to apply closures. Thanks.)

Comment: `styling` is the closure that does that. You can also use a declaration instead of passing an expression directly to `addEventListener`, and you can also `return` the closure from `addList` so that callers of the function can use it to cross off the list item they created. Your current code just doesn't do that anywhere.

Comment: @Bergi Would you mind showing what you mean "You can also use a declaration instead of passing an expression directly to addEventListener, and you can also return the closure from addList"? I am still loss..

Comment: `function addList() { … function styling(e){ list.style.textDecoration = "line-through"; } list.addEventListener('click', styling); return styling; }`

Comment: Thank you for showing what you were implying. However, my question is since closures are meant to be called outside of the function they're currently in, what is the point of making styling as the closure? Also, if I tried to call styling function outside of addList function by writing styling() it gives me an error of styling is not defined.

Comment: `styling` already *is* a closure, and it is called from the event handler that is executed outside of your function call. And yes, `styling` is not defined outside the function, you called the return value `crossOff2`.